# Is Spyzie a scam that allows people to pull data from iCloud?

Tags: ios

Came across an iOS tracking software called “Spyzie” which allows parents to monitor kids’ data usage including call logs, messages, browsing, and many more.

One of the key features this software raises the flag for average Apple users is that it allows person A to even monitor person B’a private browsing data by just entering person’s B Apple ID.

And person A could achieve all these results by using the App on his/her own device without person B’a knowledge.

If this was true, then that means iCloud actually logs Private Browsing data which contradicts Apple’s own claim about Safari’s feature.

Apple advisors declined such possibility existed and believed “Spyzie” is lying...

I am so confused. Who’s lying on this matter and does iCloud really store private browsing data in that regard? Apple insisted that the claim is completely false and not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I downvoted this question, because you pivoted and asked a completely different question than the title.

Question 1: Is Spyzie a scam that allows people to pull data from iCloud?

Answer 1: Spyzie may indeed be a 'scam' that attempts to farm iCloud credentials. Or not. If you give it your iCloud credentials, it most definitely can pull data from iCloud.

Question 2: Is Apple lying about the data it stores, and distributing it via the iCloud API?

Answer 2: Spyzie a little disingenuous on their site. SOME features of the iPhone monitoring do not require a local app install(anything that can be pulled via Apple's mobile device management APIs), but others (like the keylogger and Private Browsing history) do. I would guess they are probably using the MDM enrollment features to push a config profile, and then using that to install their app in the background.

Comment: Thanks! For your answer. Sorry about the confusion of the question. Could you verify whether Private Browsing does store data on iCloud at all? Because if it does, it would offer the scammers like a Spyzie to take advantage of the Apple’s cloud service to sell their “tracking product”.

Answer (score -1):

Spyzie is a Chinese key logger and has the ability to access all of your data if it is installed on a given device. If you have a banking application on your phone they could even access your accounts if you do not have two factor verification enabled. The worst part about Spyzie is they are based in China. I would never trust my personal information or the information of someone I care about with an application like Spyzie that is based in China. Spyzie has filled the Internet with fake testimonials that are written in poorly structured English, so it is obvious they are fake. I would recommend that you read the trust pilot Spyzie reviews because they are real and verified. Spyzie has something like a one star review and everyone claims about it not working properly and the company stealing their money. So is Spyzie safe? According to my personal experience and the reviews I have read from real customers the answer is no. Is Spyzie trustworthy? This also comes as a no from me and 80% of their customers. Spyzie is a Chinese key logger that can indeed have access to everything on the device and who knows what they do with it after that?

Comment: While I can't comment on the truthfulness of your statements, it would certainly help if you would back your claims with sources. Because without, any souces, it's just claims.

Comment: Thanks, They are based in China this is a fact, the trust pilot reviews are a fact and verified. I tested this software and it did not work as promised and they did not refund me despite buying it 4 days earlier. The rest may be my opinion but these are facts. They do offer key logging, so if you put Spyzie on a spouse's phone and they have a banking app on that phone. It is reasonable to assume that data will go to their Chinese servers.

Comment: A company being based in china is not equal to them being a scam. If you consider trust pilot reviews a legitimate source of information, I would highly recommend [edit]ing your answer to include links to it. Personal experience, sadly, is anecdotal at best. I'm not accusing you of lying, so please don't interpret it as such. It's just a matter of fact that anecdotal evidence is not verifiable for a third party.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and advice as an OG :) and I agree that the location is not a sign of fraud, I just removed the words steal and toned it down. My experience was negative and they did not refund me. The app is a key logger even by their own description, so it really could grab everything a user types. We don't know how that data is stored, so I would say anyone show beware of installing a key logger without some risk.

Comment: This is certainly a more reasonable description of the situation. I understand that you feel frustrated by the situation, but Stack Exchange aims at providing neutral, fact-based questions and answers. Accusing something of being a scam, even if it may very well be one, is usually not seen as constructive, unless there is overwhelming evidence for such a desciption.

Comment: I should say shady and stand-alone rather than a rogue application but the same applies for all apps that require this kind of permissions unless they're proven to be trustworthy.